# share sessions with memcached between ruby and php

Tags: php, ruby, session, memcached

I want to share sessions with memcached between ruby and php,the format store into the memcached is json,and now I can read the session infomation in memcached with ruby and it works very well,but in php there is a serious problem,I can't get the session created by ruby use get($key) function in php Memcached class,I always get a "0" string.I store the php session var using

`$memcached->set("key_name",json_encode($some_array));`

It works well when I use php only.please just help me ,thks

Comment: There's a serialize method in the php ini files somewhere. Change it to use json instead of the default serializer.

Comment: I find a regular problem is not looking at the information you are trying to convert, just assuming it's right. On whichever side you are having problems, dump the string you are fetching, to screen, or a logfile, to make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: @Denis I trid to use memcached.serialisor="json" but it does not work